# Mount specific FTP folder in ubuntu

Tags: directory, ftp

I want to mount a specific folder in Ubuntu.

By default the folder that is set by the ftp server is the user's home folder. However, if I mount `ftp://server.com/my_folder` it will mount the "my_folder" folder. After I add the bookmark however, it looks like Ubuntu forgets about my folder and stores only `ftp://server.com` as after reboot when I open the bookmark I am taken directly to my ftp user's home folder.

Any hints?

Answer (score -1):

Edit your bookmark (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) and specify the remote path in the location field.